# Access the name the variables in an (indexed) array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i am writing a php code that loops an array of variables using foreach and I am trying to get the name of variable to use it in the javascript code
here's my code

```
$arr = array($devices1, $devices2, $devices3, $devices4, $devices5, $devices6);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value == '1')
        {
            echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        document.getElementById($key).checked = true;
        </script>
    ";
        }
    }
```

when i run the code, $key takes values 0,1,2 what i need is to take devices1, devices2, devices3... so the names of the variables. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: When i see `devices4 ....` n times there is already a chance that this could be written better

Comment: Sidenote: `checked == true;` should most likely be `checked = true;`

Comment: thats for the sake of the question, i just need to know how can i tell php to take the variable name not the values or indexes @true

Comment: sorry @Fred-ii- i edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can build the names your self ("devices" + ($key+1)) or make it an associative array (<strike>though it doesn't make much sense</strike>):

```
$arr = array('devices1'=>$devices1,'devices2'=>$devices2,'devices3'=>$devices3);// etc...
```

However, what makes the most sense is to use a simple string array:

```
$arr = array('devices1', 'devices2', 'devices3', 'devices4', 'devices5', 'devices6');
```

and then just use $value instead of $key in your JS snippet.

---

UPDATE

Here's how to use the associative array version:

FULL CODE

```
$arr = array('devices1'=>$devices1,'devices2'=>$devices2,'devices3'=>$devices3);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if($value == '1') // $value will be the value of each array item
    {
        echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    document.getElementById($key).checked = true; // and $key is the string key
    </script>                                     // like 'devices1', etc.
";
    }
}
```

Comment: but if i do this, i will loose the values stored in it no?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the values.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you needed the values - if you do, go with the associative array.

Comment: i need the values in the if condition, i was trying to say that if devices1 contains 1 for example, i need to check its checkbox

Comment: Got it, I thought they were just being 0,1,2, etc. Use associative array and you'll be able to use both the keys and the values.

Comment: can you advise me how to use it ? i dont have an idea about it

Comment: Just use that first line I gave you. I've updated my answer to see what I mean.